# Android ksoap2 wsdl

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I´am using ksoap2 library. And I need to get namespace, method name, url and action name from http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String METHOD_NAME = "checkVat";
String NAMESPACE = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat";
String SOAP_ACTION = "";
String URL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";
```